# Since sudden restart Chrome freezes computer

Tags: windows, google-chrome, freeze

My computer suddenly restarted itself the other day and when it came back up so much as clicking on the icon to launch Google Chrome froze everything.

I tried to re-installed Chrome, but as soon as the download finished, the computer froze again. I tried installing an earlier version (about a week prior) and it froze differently - but still froze.

I am also getting a notification that the battery needs to be replaced. At the moment I am running it sans battery and using Firefox - and everything seems to be fine.

My computer is HP dv4t running Windows 7.

Comment: How long have you had the computer, as in, how old's the battery? Is it the original battery for the PC?

Comment: What antivirus u r using? Try to load ur pc with other apps or some games and c if it freezes or not? when u use this just keep open your taskmanager .....rply after u have done this

Comment: So it *only* happens when trying to run Chrome? Can you uninstall it and then reinstall?

Comment: -The computer and battery are both around 3 years old. It's the original battery. -I'm using Avast antivirus, everything else works fine. I can browse in firefox with no issues. -I have tried to uninstall and reinstall chrome multiple times. As soon as the install finishes, the computer freezes. When I restart chrome is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to Chrome's extensions. Start Chrome in `Incognito` mode to see if it freezes. Disable all your extensions and enable it one-by-one, and you should be able to narrow down to the extension that is causing the problem.